# liferay-ui input date clear value

Tags: java, html, liferay, liferay-aui

How can I achieve a clear starting value for liferay-ui:input-date ?

When I try to use this:

```
<liferay-ui:input-date
monthParam="month"
monthValue="0"
monthNullable="<%= true %>"
dayParam="day"
dayValue="0"
dayNullable="<%= true %>"
yearParam="year"
yearValue="0"
yearNullable="<%= true %>"
/>
```

I get the following exception:

```
Attribute monthNullable invalid for tag input-date according to TLD
```

which I understand. When I remove the Nullable parameter and just set values to 0 the initial value is 12/31/1902... What I need to achieve, is to have no initial value of this field, unless it is chosen. Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: additional to question... I've got <%@ taglib prefix="liferay-ui" uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" %> in my jsp, in doc of ui theres specified a dayNullable as a parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Liferay 6.2 InputDateTag has only one *nullable parameter - nullable. There's no monthNullable, dayNullable or yearNullable parameter. Hence the exception "Attribute *Nullable invalid for tag input-date according to TLD".

All you need is to set nullable="true" and the initial value will be an empty String.

The tag does the following:

`value="<%= nullable ? "" : format.format(calendar.getTime()) %>"`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. `Attribute nullable invalid for tag input-date according to TLD` is thrown.. I see theres a nullable tag in ui https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/util-taglib/src/com/liferay/taglib/ui/InputDateTag.java but when I set nullable="true" following exception is thrown. This is my html code
`<liferay-ui:input-date name="createDate" nullable="true"
      dayParam="dd" monthParam="MM"
      yearParam="yyyy" ></liferay-ui:input-date>`
I'm a bit confused with this.

Comment: What Liferay version do you use?

Comment: Most likely you have an outdated version of liferay-ui taglib on your classpath. I see the older versions did support separate *Nullable attributes (e.g. monthNullable). I suggest to search your classpath for *.tld files to find and remove the old version.

Comment: Yes I've just checked the taglib doesn't have nullable attributes, thank you for your help, will mark your answer :)